# AdMob banner ad request fails with code ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST 1

Tags: android, admob, banner

I'm having some problems with showing an AdMob banner. I get error 1 which means `ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST`. When I change the `setAdUnitId` and use an `UnitId` for testing, it works. But when I use my `UnitId` provided from `AdMob`, I get the error.

This is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#262626"
            tools:context="com.elis91.elis.contatti.Contatti">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#1e88e6"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5MSGnonLetti"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="You have 0 new messagges"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#cdfff9f9"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout3"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@+id/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Android:

```
    private void setupGoogleAds(){
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();

    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            Log.d("esx", "onAdOpened");
            // Save app state before going to the ad overlay.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            Log.d("esx", "onAdLoaded");
            // Save app state before going to the ad overlay.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {

            Log.d("esx", "onAdFailedToLoad: " + errorCode+"--"+AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL+"-"+AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR+"-"+AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST+"-"+AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR+"-");
            // Save app state before going to the ad overlay.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            Log.d("esx", "onAdClosed");
            // Save app state before going to the ad overlay.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            Log.d("esx", "onAdLeftApplication");
            // Save app state before going to the ad overlay.
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST** means:

> The ad request was invalid; for instance, the ad unit ID was
>   incorrect.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.html#ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST)

**Check if you are passing the correct ad unit id.**

I checked your code and think the issue is here.

You've written

```
ads:adUnitId="@+id/banner_ad_unit_id"
```

You must have meant to write

```
ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
```

assuming you've stored the ad unit id in your string resources. If it is not in your string resource put it directly as follows:

```
ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" // Replace XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX with your ad unit id.
```

Comment: Thx man,  the problem was the @+id/, I changet to @string/ and worked